# Is it safe to open different shared memory windows in MPI?

Tags: mpi, shared-memory

I am writing a pure-MPI code in which I need several variables to be shared among all the tasks within a shared memory communicator.
Is it safe to use different windows? E.g.: is there *any* risk of these windows to be overlapping in physical memory?

```
! number: number of elements in var1 and var2, number=n1*n2
! varsize: size_of(double), size of each element of var1 and var2
! shape: shape of var1 and var2, shape[n1,n2]

type(c_ptr) :: baseptr
integer(kind=mpi_address_kind) :: varsize,lb
integer :: dispunit
integer :: number
integer :: shape(2)
double precision, pointer, dimension(:,:) :: var1,var2
integer :: window_1,window_2

if(rank.eq.0)then
 ! only #0 allocates memory, others get zero memory
 call mpi_type_get_extent(mpi_double_precision,lb,varsize,ierr)
 dispunit=varsize
elseif(rank.gt.leader)then
 varsize=0
 dispunit=1
endif

! allocate var1
call mpi_win_allocate_shared(number*varsize,dispunit,mpi_info_null,part_comm,baseptr,window_1,ierr)
! get location of memory segment
if(rank.gt.0)then
  call mpi_win_shared_query(window_1,0,number*varsize,dispunit,baseptr,ierr)
endif
! associate C pointer to Fortran pointer
call c_f_pointer(baseptr,var1,shape)

! allocate var2
call mpi_win_allocate_shared(number*varsize,dispunit,mpi_info_null,part_comm,baseptr,window_2,ierr)
! get location of memory segment
if(rank.gt.0)then
  call mpi_win_shared_query(window_2,0,number*varsize,dispunit,baseptr,ierr)
endif
! associate C pointer to Fortran pointer
call c_f_pointer(baseptr,var2,shape)
```

Is there any possibility that var1 and var2 may overwrite each other (same physical address in memory)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had a quick look and I can't find anything in the standard, but var1 and var2 *must* be non-overlapping otherwise it would be impossible to write any useful code. If var1 and var2 were normal allocatable arrays, then it would be guaranteed that the allocated memory would be completely distinct after a Fortran allocate call. The same has to be true of MPI_Win_allocate_shared() for it to be useful in any way.

Comment: That was exactly my thought, just wanted to be sure, as I couldn't find anything in the MPI standard for the mpi_win_allocate_shared. It makes sense that they should allocate different chunks of memory, but as I didn't find any explicit confirmation, I wanted to be 100% sure.

Comment: keep in mind a window consume resources and a good practice is to keep a minimum of them. For example, in Open MPI, a communicator is created for each window, and a naive approach can lead to exhausting all the communicator ids.